# Display character symbols in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to display a character symbol (Not alphanumeric, or on the keyword)

textField.text = ???;

I have the unicode for that char, how do I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. But the font you are using must have the characters, and they must be embedded.